# What if a process has been killed while its activities are still alive?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

To my limited knowledge, in Android, any activity must belong to a given process. However, the book [Hello, Android](http://pragprog.com/book/eband/hello-android) says: " The activity life cycle is not tied to the process life cycle." that is to say, even if the process has been completely killed, its activities can still be alive!

What makes me confused is: Because the input handlers of an activity are bound to the process. If the process has been killed, how do its activities react to the user's inputs?

Comment: I think "the activity life cycle is not tied to the process life cycle" means exactly the opposite: activities are created and destroyed while a process is running. When a process is killed its activities will not survive it.

Comment: Let me give the full text: "In Android, an application can be “alive” even if its process has been killed. Put another way, the activity life cycle is not tied to the process life cycle. Processes are just disposable containers for activities. This is probably different from every other system you’re familiar with, so let’s take a closer look before moving on."

Comment: Well, a process can be terminated (say from a low memory condition) and later a new activity can be created from the old state, but it's not the _same_ Activity object. It's probable referring to this, but I don't think it's a particularly clear way to put it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` is not alive in the sense that it's running and its input handlers are running, just that all the information needed to restore the `Activity` is stored by the OS so it can recreate it at will.

Recreating the whole application at the state it was when you left recreates all the input handlers too.

Answer (score 0):

When a process is killed all of the application components (activities, services etc.) will be destroyed. But when process with alive foreground activity dies it will be restarted (as well as the activity).